# Possible to remove this kind of string from a file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is the functionality I describe below possible using Batch Windows Scripting? And if so how I can I edit my code to perform this functionality?

I am attempting to remove a multiline string from a file. The multiline string comes from another file and is read into a Batch variable. I then read the target file and search for this multiline string, if it exists I want to delete it from the target file.

My code below is unable to remove the multiline string from the target file. It can successfully read the input file. **Can you help me edit my script to search for and remove a multiline string from a file?**

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set replace=
Set target=
Set infile=usermenuTest1.4d
Set outfile=usermenuTest2.4d

Rem Read file and store all contents in string
for /f "delims=" %%i in (%infile%) do set "target=!target! %%i"
echo %target%

Rem Remove the target string from outfile
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( 'type "%outfile%"') do SET "string=%%A"
SET "modified=!string:%target%=%replace%!"
(echo(%modified%)>> "%outfile%"

ECHO.
PAUSE
ENDLOCAL
```

Essentially I want my script to remove the following **bold(the text inside **)** text from a file:

> ```
> // abc
>
> // def
>
> // hij
>
> **Menu "User" {
>    Button "" {
>       Walk_Right ""
>    }
> }**
> ```

Comment: Do you need to use batch? can't you use powershell or vbs?

Comment: @Carko does Powershell or VBS scripts work on Windows XP and up? I am distributing a installer that will call this script so the user needs to be able to compile and run the script. Python would be easiest but not everyone will have Python Interpreter installed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off & setlocal
Set "infile=usermenuTest1.4d"
Set "outfile=usermenuTest2.4d"
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%i in ('^<"%infile%" findstr /n "^"') do (
    echo(%%j|findstr /lc:"Menu \"User\"" >nul && set /a counter=6
    set /a counter-=1
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    if !counter! leq 0 (echo(%%j)>>"%outfile%"
    endlocal
)
```